# Compute Irreducible Infeasible Set (IIS) in Pyomo

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, gurobi, pyomo, irreducible-infeasible-subset

I am using Pyomo together with Gurobi (and other solvers such as cbc). I am trying to compute an Irreducible Infeasible Set (ISS).

In Pyomo [documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyomo/downloads/pdf/latest/), `get_model_attr` takes an attribute, among which `'IISMinimal'`. On the other hand Gurobi [documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/iisminimal.html) states that "this attribute is only available after you have computed an IIS on an infeasible model". However I haven't found how to actually compute an IIS for a given infeasible model.

To give more context to this question, I am trying to determine which constraints make my problem infeasible. I've read about the subject ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044262/finding-out-reason-of-pyomo-model-infeasibility) and [there](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/how-to-find-out-which-constraint-causes-problems-in-pyomo) for example) but as several users user state in their comments, I haven't been able to make it work so far.

Comment: Very old, so no idea whether there is an easier way to do it now in Pyomo: https://groups.google.com/g/pyomo-forum/c/9n5KAg2nKDk  and https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/examples/pyomo/suffixes/gurobi_ampl_iis.py . I found this by random googling, so can't offer any assistance.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks for your comment, but the references use AMPL, and I'd like to access gurobi solver directly

Comment: That;s why it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gurobi documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_computeiis.html) states how you can compute and inspect the IIS:

```
model.computeIIS()
model.write("model.ilp")
```

I am not certain how to call the `computeIIS()` method from Pyomo, though. This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522718/get-gurobi-iis-using-pyomo-and-gurobipy) might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read this doc, but indeed it doesn't help to make it work from pyomo. I'll check the related question and come back to you

Comment: The related question indeed provides an answer to my initial question. Caveats are: 1/ working with gurobi, not working with cbc and 2/ *.ilp file is difficult to read because all variabless and constraints names in the initial model are replaced by `x` and `c_u_x`, `c_l_x` and `c_e_x`.

Comment: The variable names are actually preserved when writing out a Gurobi ILP file. I can only assume that the variable names have been changed when transferring the model from Pyomo to Gurobi. You might want to try saving the Pyomo model to a file and then using Gurobi directly to compute the IIS.

Answer (score -1):

An excellent reference on infeasibility analysis is the book:
Chinneck, John (2008)
"Feasibility and Infeasibility in Optimization Algorithms and Computational Methods"
Springer.
Looks like it may be downloadable as a pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll have a look. I doubt the book answers to ma initial question though (the book doesn't make any reference to pyomo or gurobi it seems).